# Handling Rating widgets

Tags: selenium, firefox, tripadvisor

Trying to give five stars for all three bubble rating widgets in[tripadvisor] as below shown in screenshot with following code, but only the first rating widget is being clicked in chrome.
And while in Firefox it is throwing MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException.

- Link
  (https://www.tripadvisor.in/UserReviewEdit-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html)
- Code

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#qid12_bubbles"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#qid13_bubbles"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#qid14_bubbles"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
```

- Browser snapshot

[image: Browser Snapshot]

Comment: which programming language you are using..??

Comment: Java @HietshKumar

Comment: The elements you have identified as `cssSelector("#qid12_bubbles")`, `cssSelector("#qid13_bubbles")` and `cssSelector("#qid1_bubbles")` may/maynot be visible in the same run, as the second item is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The Id which you are using is dynamic.Try use following `xpath`.

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[1]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[2]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[3]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
```

**Browser snapshot.**

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

For `firefox` browser you need to `scroll` to get the focus of the `element` and then perform the operation.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[1]"))));
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[1]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[2]"))));
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[2]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[3]"))));
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Hotel Ratings']/following::span[3]"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: How did u get those xpaths? @KunduK

Comment: If you go to chrome dev tool you will find those xpath. Target the Hotel ratings tag and then following span tag.

Comment: No need to use Thread.sleep() since you are already using explicit wait.

Comment: The other issue is while I am running it in firefox it throws an exception called
MoveTargetOutOfBound

Comment: @SaiSharan : check my updated answer on firefox and let me know the status?you need to scroll the element and then use action class.